# Why can't I access this associative array value?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "275" ["course"]=> string(2) "92" 
["name"]=> string(33) "Tutorial - Transforming 2D Shapes" ["activitylink"]=> string(4) 
"2488" ["available"]=> string(10) "1330626600" ["deadline"]=> string(10) "1330630200" } }

array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "422" ["course"]=> string(3) "130" 
["name"]=> string(8) "tester 2" ["activitylink"]=> string(1) "0" ["available"]=> 
string(10) "1330691375" ["deadline"]=> string(10) "1330694135" } }

 array(1) { [0]=>   array(6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "423" ["course"]=> string(3) "132"      ["name"]=> string(10) "LessonName" ["activitylink"]=> string(1) "0" ["available"]=> string(10)
 "1330770900" ["deadline"]=> string(10) "1330781700" } }
```

I am retrieving data from a function where it returns an array of Lessons and the information about it.

I am able to do `var_dump($lessonArray)` and the result is the bit of output I've pasted here. However, I am trying to access the `available` field with no success. I've done `var_dump($lessonArray['available'])` and `print_r($lessonArray['available'])` but all it returns is `NULL`.

Comment: Using `print_r()` is probably better here - it gives much cleaner, easier to understand results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the three cases you posted, you actually have **nested arrays**. This `array(1) { [0]=>` indicates that **the first array contains a key 0**. And this `array(1) { [0]=>   array(6)` indicates that **the key 0 of the first array is a second array**.

Thus, `$lessonArray[0]` should be:

```
array(6) { ["id"]=> string(3) "422" ["course"]=> string(3) "130" 
["name"]=> string(8) "tester 2" ["activitylink"]=> string(1) "0" ["available"]=> 
string(10) "1330691375" ["deadline"]=> string(10) "1330694135" }
```

And `$lessonArray[0]['name']` should be 'tester 2', `$lessonArray[0]['available']` should be '1330691375' and so on.

If you had used **print_r($lessonArray)** instead of `var_dump($lessonArray)`, you would have spotted the difference :)

So I second **JamWaffles comment to use print_r**, I myself prefer print_r unless I really want to get picky on the types of the values.

Comment: Hey, you're right. It was a nested array. The data I've retrieved is from mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and I'm guessing this function makes it a nested array. Is there a way around this when retrieving data from the database so it returns a normal array where I can access it like lesson['available']? Lesson[0]['avaiable'] seems a bit messy to me...

Comment: @user1219572: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` only once, not in a loop.

Comment: **Is there a way around this when retrieving data from the database so it returns a normal array where I can access it like lesson['available']?** I'd have to see your code. Please, close this question and open another one, paste your code there.

Answer (score 0):

They're all arrays within single-element arrays. Just use `$lessonArray[0]['available']` instead of `$lessonArray['available']`, or retrieve element `0` to begin with.